# Power BI: How I can set default values for cards which Should Not Update with Slicer

Tags: powerbi, measure

I had a sample screenshot, and want to create it using Power BI Desktop. here in red rounded border rectangle are 4 Cards Visuals, all 4 visuals are have same measure LatestPrice which is within its Data Table. first (left most) card can change values as user selects a Country in Slicer above and other 3 will NOT change. how I can achieve this using Format -> Edit Interactions (this hint given by my manager to achieve), i tried but failed to have 3 cards visuals can have values from measure and will not interact with Slicer.
screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you click `Format -> Edit Interactions`, all visualisations get little icons at the top right. Click the slicer then click the "disable" icon at the top right on the three visuals that you want to ignore the slicer

Comment: thanks @Nick.McDermaid for quick response, when Disabling with clicking on a small Circle with little line to half, which tooltip is None, right side of Filter, its now changed color from white to black, in this case it is not showing any data instead showing (Blank).

Comment: Does this help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQsRHWTF4Bs

Comment: as mentioned, this works as per you already have instructed but what remains the 3 visuals are not showing any value in my visual but as per screenshot it is showing valid values (latestprice) , mine is showing (Blank) -in comments i can't share my visual's screenshot).

Comment: I don't have any visibility on your data. I guess you need to adjust filters against your visuals until you get a value.

Comment: ok, thanks for your interest to help.

Comment: For example, you need to click in the Switzerland visual then you need to click on the filters tab, go in and fiddle with the fixed filters until you see the required value